# preg_replace with php

Tags: php, regex

I would like to replace ":" with "\xEF\xBC\x9A" however, I do not want to do this for : that follows "http", "https", and string with the format of @[{numbers}:{numbers}:{some text}].
What I have doesn't really work as `(?<!@\[\d)` does not check what's after it. My current implementation only work for something like `@[1:2:text]`. Thanks!

```
$string=preg_replace('#(?<!https)(?<!http)(?<!@\[\d)(?<!@\[\d:\d):#', "\xEF\xBC\x9A", $string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/(@\[\d+:\d+:[^]]*]|https?:)|:/e', '"$1"?"$1":"\xEF\xBC\x9A"', $string);
```

Comment: Umm I am getting 
Unknown modifier 'g': [/(@\[\d+:\d+:[^]]*]|https?:)|:/ge]

Comment: This appears to select instances of 'http:', 'https:', and '@[/d:/d:/t*]', which is opposing the point made in the question itself, I suggest rewording the question if this is the correct answer.

Comment: @Qtax, is there a way I can do this without /e?

Comment: @Dessix: The idea is to capture the "ineligible" colon along with the text preceding it, and plug it back in.  That "gets it out of the way", so when the other alternative matches a colon, you know it's one of the ones you want to replace.

Comment: @hao: You *can* do this without `/e`, but I don't recommend it: [demo](http://ideone.com/QeSWB).

Comment: @hao, why is `/e` a problem? @Alan, +1 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?<!@\[(?::?[\d]{0,5}){1,2})(?<!https?):
```

It should match the first and second instances of '**:**' here.

```
: test: http: @[1:2:text]
```

Usage Sample:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(?<!@\[(?::?[\d]{0,5}){1,2})(?<!https?):/', '\xEF\xBC\x9A', $string);
```

Comment: A lookbehind has to match a fixed number of characters (in PHP, at least).  That's why the OP used `(?<!https)(?<!http)` instead of `(?<!https?)`.  But it's impossible to "fake" the whole problem that way, as the OP has discovered.